# VSCode terminal taking two keyboard inputs when only one key is pressed on keyboard

Tags: linux, bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, google-chrome-os

In the vscode terminal bash if i press a key it takes two inputs. For example if I press 'a' the terminal shows 'aa' and this happens for all the keys. But it doesn’t happen on the default terminal. I'm using dual boot windows 11 with fyde os. On windows there is no such issue and i've been using vscode on it for years. But in my fyde os i installed the linux environment and then the debian version of vscode. The linux terminal has no such problem in while typing. The vscode terminal bash is only doing this. I've tried other shell but it's the same result. In the code writing section there is no problem in typing. Only the terminal section of vs code is doing this.How do i fix this?

I tried writing text in the vscode terminal but the terminal is taking two keyboard input for each keyboard press

Comment: "_I've tried other shell but it's the same result_" what other shell? Do you mean you tried that other shell in VS Code's integrated terminal? "_The linux terminal has no such problem in while typing_" what terminal? What is the terminal application you are referring to here called?

Comment: Related? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143103 or https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102107 (from googling "`github vscode issues integrated terminal duplicates input characters`")

Comment: yes other shell in the vs code. I've tried zsh but it's the same. The terminal having no problem is the default terminal app. the problem only happens in vscode terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but don't know it'll work for other's or not.As i'm using linux virtual environment on fyde os i installed the debian version of vscode which was recomended everywhere for fyde and chrome os. I uninstalled it and used flatpacks on linux. Then installed vs code from flathub. Now the vscode terminal has no such issue. what i found out that flapacks install linux apps without worrying about dependencies and distros.